# selenium python: Unable to parse data in <object> tag with #document section

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
url = 'http://www.mtv.de/charts/c6mc86/single-top-100?expanded=true'
chromedriver = Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=chromedriver, options=op)
browser.get(url)
timeout = 60
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight,)")
time.sleep(5)
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div/section/div/div/div/object')))
    print('========================')
except TimeoutException:
    browser.quit()
items = browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'object'))
print(items)
itembox = items.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'charts-marslnet')
# print(itembox)
for item in itembox:
    print(item.text)
```

I have been trying to scrap the song name, author and url for the song from this website but unable to access the html inside the  tag under #document section. I am not able to figure why i cant access it. Any insights on what can be the issue with my code or what should be done to access this html inside #document section would be very helpful.
[HTML inside the  tag with #document(Screenshot 2[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvlPz.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO!! Read [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly, it will increase chances of addressing your question properly and spot on!!

Comment: Sure will do. I thought more code is better than less. Sometimes info is not enough.But you never know who starts complaining. For example: you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab it from the direct url:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://mtv.marsl.net/demo/showdbcharts.php?c=4'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

acts = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'cmn-act'})
for each in acts:
    title = each.find_next('div', {'class':'cmn-title'}).text.strip()
    artist = each.find_next('div', {'class':'cmn-artist'}).text.strip()
    link = each.find_next('a', href=True)['href']
    
    print(f'{title}\n{artist}\n{link}\n\n')
```

**Output:**

```
abcdefu
Gayle
https://www.mtv.de/musikvideos/r9d9sl/abcdefu


Wenn ich will
Gzuz & Bonez MC
https://www.mtv.de/musikvideos/7evkst/10von10


10von10
Pajel
https://www.mtv.de/musikvideos/7evkst/10von10


Shivers
Ed Sheeran
https://www.mtv.de/musikvideos/miq9lq/shivers


Heat Waves
Glass Animals
https://www.mtv.de/musikvideos/l9rv5d/heat-waves

...
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for this insight. It works now. However, i still am not able to capture the 100th element . it shows only 99 records. Here is a screenshot. [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/0ZhhdJn)

Comment: Just solved the issue. Thank you so much for sorting me out. I would have never thought of scraping from the url in the <object> tag. :)